# In iOS, should self be casted to "id" when assigning to tableView's dataSource and delegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I only see code doing:

```
tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource = self;
```

but it does give warnings on XCode 4.3.  Do we need to cast it and is `id` the proper type to cast?  (so should be the following:)

```
tableview.delegate = (id) self;
tableview.dataSource = (id) self;
```

Comment: no, it probably gives warnings because you didn't declare your class as conforming to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You should not be casting to `id` direct assignment should be fine if your code is setup correctly.

The problem is you are trying to cheat your way out of conforming to a **protocol** by hiding our true object type by casting to `(id)`. This is bad practice and should be avoided! The table view expects both its `delegate` and `dataSource` members to implement certain methods that it will call. **Protocols** (similar to interfaces in Java) help ensure that delegates implement all required methods and will throw warnings when you try and misuse an object does not implement all required methods or does not declare itself to support a protocol.

To fix the warning you are having correctly, modify your class interface declaration (usually in the header) to look something like this:

`@interface MyObject : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

The items inside the <> declare a list what protocols your class will support.

You can read more about protocols here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html

Answer (score 2):

The most possible problem you are facing is probably you are not extending the required protocols for the tableview.

In your .h file be sure to add the following code with your interface declaration.

```
@interface HomeScreenViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

then set the

```
yourTableName.delegate =self;
yourTableName.dataSource=self;
```

If you are creating this control on a story board you can always control-drag from the table view to the files owner and select the delegate and source. 
[image]